# PSQL throwing error: relation "serial" does not exist, when creating a table

Tags: postgresql, auto-increment

It happens when i run this code:

```
CREATE TABLE distributors (
 did    integer PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT nextval('serial'),
 name   varchar(40) NOT NULL CHECK (name <> '')
);
```

I have tried remover the nextval('serial') but to no avail

Comment: You shouldn't be using `serial` any more to begin with. use `did integer primary key generated always as identity`

Answer (score 2):

You want to do this:

```
CREATE TABLE distributors (
 did    serial PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT,
 name   varchar(40) NOT NULL CHECK (name <> '')
);
```

The `serial` type is actually a macro. That per docs ([Serial](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL)) does:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq AS integer;
CREATE TABLE tablename (
    colname integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('tablename_colname_seq')
);
ALTER SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq OWNED BY tablename.colname;
```

Assuming you are on a recent version(10+) of Postgres `generated always as identity`(see [Create Table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html)) is the preferred alternative these days.

Answer (score 1):

`nextval('someseries')` relies on having an existing series. You can create that with:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE someseries;
```

When you removed the nextval, you probably still had the `DEFAULT` keyword there, which expects a value afterward to define what the default for the column is.